# How to get the ID of the clicked html link?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes

Context: The user enters emails in an input field and each email creates a link with a user icon (therefore no ul list creation).
I would like to retrieve ID of the link the user clicked on in order to display specific informations.

This is how I create the user icon with the link :

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += "<div class='iconUser'>" + "<a id='relLink' onclick="getIdLink(this)" href='Annotation.html'>" + "<div id='test' class='iniUser'>" + guestStored[i] + "</div>" + "</a>" + "<div class='state'>" + stateInv[i] + "</div >" + "</div>";
var idLink = document.getElementById('relLink');
var init = guestStored[i];
idLink.setAttribute("id", init);
```

Here my function:

```
function getIdLink(lnk) {
        var x = lnk.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(x);
}
```

But getIdLink is not called.

Comment: yes, if the link has an ID you can detect it in javascript by looking at the event.target

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button-using-javascript-jquery/

Comment: I have add onclick="getIdLink(this)" but my method is not call. I will edit my post to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from "Professor Abronsius", here is my solution:

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
     var targetId = event.target.id;
});
```